# Can a set $S\subset \mathbb{P}_3$ be called a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I had a Linear Algebra exam today and we had been asked the following:

> Consider the subset $S=\{x^3-1,x^2-x,x-1\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Examine whether $S$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I think that this problem makes no sense. $S$ is a subset of the $4$ dimensional polynomial vector space where the degree is $3$, and NOT a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is this correct or am I being too ignorant?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The question asks to 'examine' and not to prove that $S$ is basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Regarding the nature of the objects polynomials with real coefficients vs tuples of real numbers, some authors define polynomials that way. So, it could make sense to say that some polynomials are elements of some $\mathbb{R}^n$. When I was undergraduate, in our algebra course, such a choice of presentation was made. Even if that were your case, the sizes of the tuples don't match.

Comment: Since it calls $S$ a subset, I suspect this was a typo, and it was intended to be "\Bbb P_3$", not "$\Bbb R^3$".